# Can the changes of the ".disabled" modifier of SwiftUI be animated?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I think that the `View.disabled(_:)` modifier changes the `.foregroundColor` of a `View` (besides enabling / disabling interactions with it). Could the color change be animated?

I know it's pretty easy to animate say `.opacity` changes with implicit animations (e.g.: `.animation(.default)`). However the same won't work with `.disabled`.

Please consider the following code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct SomeButton: View {

    @State var isDisabled = false
    @State var isHidden = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 30) {
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {}) {
                Image(systemName: "pencil.circle.fill")
                    .resizable()
            }
            .frame(width: 80, height: 80)

            .disabled(isDisabled)       //  Will not animate at all.
            .opacity(isHidden ? 0 : 1)  //  Will animate just fine.
            .animation(.default)        //  Set to use implicit animations.

            VStack(spacing: 10) {
                Button(action: {
                    self.isHidden.toggle()
                }) {
                    Text("Hide")
                }
                Button(action: {
                    self.isDisabled.toggle()
                }) {
                    Text("Disable")
                }
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Preview

#if DEBUG
struct SomeButton_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SomeButton()
    }
}
#endif
```

This produces the following result, which presents a smooth opacity transition:

[image: animationSample]

... on the other hand the enabled / disabled color transition is binary. It doesn't look that good.

My current workaround is to change the opacity of a view based on its enabled/disabled state.
So for example if a view is disabled, the opacity is 0.6. If enabled, the opacity goes back to 1.0.

But it feels wrong. There must be another way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The possible solution can be to combine with `.colorMultipy`, of course the *disabled* color should be experimentally fit, but this gives common effect animatable

[image: demo]

```
.disabled(isDisabled)
.colorMultiply(isDisabled ?  //  animatable
      Color.gray /* to be selected to fit*/ : .white)
.animation(.default, value: isDisabled)
```